# Form is not working in laravel master layout

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, forms

What i am trying to do is to submit my form but this form is not working.
If i run this code without extending my layout file its work but inside this code form is not working.
Can you check my code and tell my mistake.
Thanks in advance

**Form.blade.php**

```
 @extends('layouts.login')
    @section('title')
    TSI(New Buyer)
    @endsection
    @section('page-header')
    BUYER
    @endsection
    @section('breadcrumb1')
    Marketing
    @endsection
    @section('breadcrumb2')
    Add new buyer
    @endsection
    @section('content')
    
                <form method="POST" action="{{route('inquiry.store')}}">
                    {{ csrf_field()}}
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                    
                </form>
        
    @endsection
```

Layout file that contain the master layout

**login.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        @include('include.head')
    </head>
   
    <body class="theme-blush">

        <!-- Page Loader -->
        <div class="page-loader-wrapper">
            <div class="loader">
                <div class="m-t-30"><img class="zmdi-hc-spin" src="{{asset('assets/images/loader.svg')}}" width="48" height="48" alt="Aero"></div>
                <p>Please wait...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Overlay For Sidebars -->
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        @include('include.sidebar')
         <!-- End of Sidebar -->
        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  
            <!-- Main Content -->
            <section class="content">
                <div class="body_scroll">
                    <div class="block-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <h2> @yield('page-header')</h2>
                                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i> TSI</a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:void(0);">@yield('breadcrumb1')</a></li>
                                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">@yield('breadcrumb2')</li>
                                </ul>
                          
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-icon mobile_menu" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-sort-amount-desc"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12">     
                                @yield('plus-btn')           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        @yield('content')
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </section>
 
    @include('include.script')
   </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It could be one of the tag you forgot to close. Try without sidebar

Comment: Please define "it is not working". Start debugging the controller action and see if you even receive data. That way you know if its either a frontend or a backend problem.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?